# strip object series without deleting the int/float cells in the series

Tags: python, pandas, nan, series, strip

I have a series of type `object`, When using `Series.str.strip()` the cells that contain only `int` are getting turned into `Nan`.

How do I avoid this?

---

**example**

```
sr = pd.Series([1,2,3,'foo   '])
sr.str.strip()

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    foo
dtype: object
```

desired outcome

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    foo
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest is replace missing values by original values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
sr = pd.Series([1,2,3,'foo   '])

sr.str.strip().fillna(sr)
```

Or striping only strings tested by `isinstance`:

```
print (sr.apply(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x))

0      1
1      2
2      3
3    foo
dtype: object
```

Comment: Is it a bug the fact that it deletes data?

Comment: @moshevi - I think not, `str` working only witth strings, so for another types return NaNs

Comment: @AnuragDabas I get `In [111]: %timeit sr.apply(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
8.36 ms ± 34.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [112]: %timeit sr.map(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
8.4 ms ± 29.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` with `sr = pd.Series([1,2,3,'foo   '] * 10000)`

Comment: @jezrael ok sir pls let me know as Sir I seen many high reputation developers as they prefer `map()` over `apply()` and `agg()` when dealing with Series

Comment: @jezrael time is almost same...thanks sir for testing it **:)**

Comment: @AnuragDabas - ya, in old pandas version seems `map` was faster, today pandas functions are more effective like in past. So it depends, here seemd it is same. So I always prefer test inlast pandas version in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the series to `str` altogether and then strip:

```
>>> sr.astype(str).str.strip()

0      1
1      2
2      3
3    foo
dtype: object
```

this way `1` becomes `"1"` and remains unchanged against stripping. But they will remain strings at the end, not integers; not sure if that's the desired output.